# Regex to split words in Python

Tags: python, regex, split

I was designing a regex to **split** all the **actual words** from a given **text**:

*Input Example:*

```
"John's mom went there, but he wasn't there. So she said: 'Where are you'"
```

*Expected Output:*

```
["John's", "mom", "went", "there", "but", "he", "wasn't", "there", "So", "she", "said", "Where", "are", "you"]
```

I thought of a regex like that:

```
"(([^a-zA-Z]+')|('[^a-zA-Z]+))|([^a-zA-Z']+)"
```

After splitting in Python, the result contains `None` items and empty spaces.

How to get rid of the None items? And why didn't the spaces match?

*Edit:


Splitting on spaces, will give items like: `["there."]`


And splitting on non-letters, will give items like: `["John","s"]`


And splitting on non-letters except `'`, will give items like: `["'Where","you'"]`*

Comment: Why does it have to be a `split` and not a `findall`?

Comment: Defining what you want to match is so much simpler here: a `findall` with `r"[a-zA-Z]+(?:'[a-z])?"` does the job. So I'm really curious for the reason to want a `split`.

Comment: Another update for a bug fix. Now it can capture single letters follows by with an apostrophe in the begining or the end.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling Yeah, I think that's much easier, Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Instead of regex, you can use string-functions:

```
to_be_removed = ".,:!" # all characters to be removed
s = "John's mom went there, but he wasn't there. So she said: 'Where are you!!'"

for c in to_be_removed:
    s = s.replace(c, '')
s.split()
```

**BUT**, in your example you do not want to remove apostrophe in `John's` but you wish to remove it in `you!!'`. So string operations fails in that point and you need a finely adjusted regex.

EDIT: probably a simple regex can solve your porblem:

```
(\w[\w']*)
```

It will capture all chars that starts with a letter and keep capturing while next char is an apostrophe or letter.

```
(\w[\w']*\w)
```

This second regex is for a very specific situation.... First regex can capture words like `you'`. This one will aviod this and only capture apostrophe if is is within the word (not in the beginning or in the end). But in that point, a situation raises like, you can not capture the apostrophe `Moss' mom` with the second regex. You must decide whether you will capture trailing apostrophe in names ending wit *s* and defining ownership.

Example:

```
rgx = re.compile("([\w][\w']*\w)")
s = "John's mom went there, but he wasn't there. So she said: 'Where are you!!'"
rgx.findall(s)

["John's", 'mom', 'went', 'there', 'but', 'he', "wasn't", 'there', 'So', 'she', 'said', 'Where', 'are', 'you']
```

UPDATE 2: I found a bug in my regex! It can not capture single letters followed by an apostrophe like `A'`. Fixed brand new regex is here:

```
(\w[\w']*\w|\w)

rgx = re.compile("(\w[\w']*\w|\w)")
s = "John's mom went there, but he wasn't there. So she said: 'Where are you!!' 'A a'"
rgx.findall(s)

["John's", 'mom', 'went', 'there', 'but', 'he', "wasn't", 'there', 'So', 'she', 'said', 'Where', 'are', 'you', 'A', 'a']
```

Comment: `a.findall(s)` won't work because there's no `a` defined. Instead, that line should be `re.findall(rgx,s)`

Comment: Opss, I forget to change variable names. Thank you, error fixed.

Comment: Also, I noticed that the final regexp misses single-letter words like 'a' etc.

Comment: Because regex is `(\w[\w']*\w|\w)` but I forgot to replace it in my final example. Fixed

Comment: @meyer1994 yes, my test confirms that regex is working with multi-line texts too.

Comment: Hi @FallenAngel Found some cases not supported by version2, one example: "the students’ books, the children’s toys"

Answer (score 9):

You have too many capturing groups in your regular expression; make them non-capturing:

```
(?:(?:[^a-zA-Z]+')|(?:'[^a-zA-Z]+))|(?:[^a-zA-Z']+)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "John's mom went there, but he wasn't there. So she said: 'Where are you!!'"
>>> re.split("(?:(?:[^a-zA-Z]+')|(?:'[^a-zA-Z]+))|(?:[^a-zA-Z']+)", s)
["John's", 'mom', 'went', 'there', 'but', 'he', "wasn't", 'there', 'So', 'she', 'said', 'Where', 'are', 'you', '']
```

That returns only *one* element that is empty.

Comment: I thought of that simplified version before, but the problem is something like "she said 'go'" will result in [ ...., "'go'"], which is not correct

Comment: @Betamoo: Yeah, adjusting, as I see where you ended up with your expression so far (missed a parenthesis).

Comment: @VishalSuthar: Sorry, but your edit was rubbish. "non-capturing" is normal word, not something that needs to be rendered as code.

Comment: I just had a totally different problem but changing `?` to `?:`also solved it! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This regex will only allow one ending apostrophe, which may be followed by one more character:

```
([\w][\w]*'?\w?)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "John's mom went there, but he wasn't there. So she said: 'Where are you!!' 'A a'"
>>> re.compile("([\w][\w]*'?\w?)").findall(s)
["John's", 'mom', 'went', 'there', 'but', 'he', "wasn't", 'there', 'So', 'she', 'said', 'Where', 'are', 'you', 'A', "a'"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to python but i think i have figured it out

```
import re
s = "John's mom went there, but he wasn't there. So she said: 'Where are you!!'"
result = re.findall(r"(.+?)[\s'\",!]{1,}", s)
print(result)
```

result
['John', 's', 'mom', 'went', 'there', 'but', 'he', 'wasn', 't', 'there.', 'So', 'she', 'said:', 'Where', 'are', 'you']

Comment: Your answer splits `John's` into `John` and `s` and it keeps the : in `said:`. I appreciate you're trying to contribute but this question already have answers that accomplish exactly what was asked, consider helping out on other questions that don't have ideal answers yet. Still, thanks for trying to contribute.