# is there any faster way to replace words to their roots (which are all in dictionary)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I try to change words to their roots quickly , I have found a way to make it but it is very slow, zargan is the dictionary of roots and words

```
for a in range(1,500): 
    for j in data.txt[a].split():
         pattern = r'\b'+j+r'\b' 
         data.TXT[a] = re.sub(pattern,str(zargan.get(j,j)),data.TXT[a])
```

I have thousands of text row and try to make it quicker than above

Answer (score 1):

Match each word and use a replacement function to look up its replacement:

```
pattern = r'\w*' 
data.TXT[a] = re.sub(pattern, lambda m: zargan.get(m.group(0), m.group(0))), data.TXT[a])
```

An example of this is

```
>>> import re
>>> x = "This is an example"
>>> zargan = {'This':'Not', 'is':'here', 'an':'again', 'example':'tomorrow'}
>>> pattern = r'\w*' 
>>> re.findall(pattern, x)
['This', '', 'is', '', 'an', '', 'example', '']
>>> y = re.sub(pattern, lambda m: zargan.get(m.group(0), m.group(0)), x)
>>> y
'Not here again tomorrow'
```

This is a lot faster as it does a single pass over the string.

Also [Regex to split words in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705293/regex-to-split-words-in-python)