# Create a list of alphabetically sorted UNIQUE words and display the first N words in python

Tags: python, string, sorting, alphabetical

I am new to Python, apologize for a simple question. My task is the following:

**Create a list of alphabetically sorted unique words and display the first 5 words**

I have `text` variable, which contains a lot of text information

I did

```
test = text.split()
sorted(test)
```

As a result, I receive a list, which starts from symbols like `$` and numbers.

How to get to words and print N number of them.

[image]

Comment: what do you define as *word*? As far as the 2nd question goes, just slice the list you create with `sorted`

Comment: Are you only concerned about alphabetical words? As in, do you simply want to print the first 5 strings that contain only alphabets and forget about the rest?

Comment: A great question. I was thinking that I need to print REAL words, not just first 5 elements.

Comment: @Chase, yes, that would be great. How to do it?

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker have a look at python's built-in `filter`, list slicing and the `regex` library. That should get you going

Comment: What exactly does "unique words" mean? Does it mean words that literally appear only once in the input list, or just different words regardless of how often they appear?

Comment: @ekhumoro, personally I would say a unique word is a string, consisting of letters, and this string does not repeat. Like you mentioned below - five times a is not unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming by "word", you mean strings that consist of only alphabetical characters. In such a case, you can use [`.filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to first get rid of the unwanted strings, turn it into a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), sort it and *then* print your stuff.

```py
text = "$1523-the king of the 521236 mountain rests atop the king mountain's peak $@"
# Extract only the words that consist of alphabets
words = filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), text.split(' '))
# Print the first 5 words
sorted(set(words))[:5]
```

Output-

```py
['atop', 'king', 'mountain', 'of', 'peak']
```

But the problem with this is that it will still ignore words like `mountain's`, because of that pesky `'`. A regex solution might actually be far better in such a case-

For now, we'll be going for this regex - `^[A-Za-z']+$`, which means the string must **only contain** alphabets and `'`, you may add more to this regex according to what you deem as "words". Read more on regexes [here](https://regexone.com/).

We'll be using [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) instead of `.isalpha` this time.

```py
WORD_PATTERN = re.compile(r"^[A-Za-z']+$")
text = "$1523-the king of the 521236 mountain rests atop the king mountain's peak $@"
# Extract only the words that consist of alphabets
words = filter(lambda x: bool(WORD_PATTERN.match(x)), text.split(' '))
# Print the first 5 words
sorted(set(words))[:5]
```

Output-

```py
['atop', 'king', 'mountain', "mountain's", 'of']
```

Keep in mind however, this gets tricky when you have a string like `hi! What's your name?`. `hi!`, `name?` are all words except they are not fully alphabetic. The trick to this is to split them in such a way that you get `hi` instead of `hi!`, `name` instead of `name?` in the first place.

Unfortunately, a true word split is far outside the scope of this question. I suggest taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705293/regex-to-split-words-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

I am newbie here, apologies for mistakes. Thank you.

```
test = '''The coronavirus outbreak has hit hard the cattle farmers in Pabna and Sirajganj as they are now getting hardly any customer for the animals they prepared for the last year targeting the Eid-ul-Azha this year.

Normally, cattle traders flock in large numbers to the belt -- one of the biggest cattle producing areas of the country -- one month ahead of the festival, when Muslims slaughter animals as part of their efforts to honour Prophet Ibrahim's spirit of sacrifice.

But the scene is different this year.'''

test = test.lower().split()

test2 = sorted([j for j in test if j.isalpha()])

print(test2[:5])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the sorted return list until the 5 position

```
sorted(test)[:5]
```

or if looking only for words

```
sorted([i for i in test if i.isalpha()])[:5]
```

or by regex

```
sorted([i for i in test if re.search(r"[a-zA-Z]")])
```

by using the slice of a list you will be able to get all list elements until a specific index in this case 5.

Comment: but OP wants to get to the actual alphabetical words, I don't think they want to print the elements that are not words

Comment: @Chase, I think so, I would do it myself. But I gave a point anyway.

Comment: @LeoArad, thanks! I get Output: ['001', '002', '002', '003', '006']. Probably because they are strings too. How to extract letters? Any idea? Appreciate your time!

Comment: Changed it to `.isalpha()` that will return only words

Comment: This doesn't get **unique** words - it just gets the first five words, which could be `['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']`.

Comment: Also this won't account for words like `mountain's`

Comment: What about `sorted([i for i in test if [char for char in i if char.isalpha()]])[:5]` ?

Comment: Or by regex `sorted([i for i in test if re.search(r"[a-zA-Z]", i)])[:5]`