# How to search a text string and know if there's a certain word?

Tags: python, string

I've written a function that searches into a text and finds a certain word, but it says that there isn't that word - but I know there is so it doesn't work.

```
def search(text, item):
    list_ = []
    p = [';', '.', ' ', ',', ':']
    string = ''
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i] not in p:
            string += text[i]
        else:
            list_ += string
            string = ''
    if item in list_:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Please share the inputs you provided'

Comment: What is the variable `n`? Is that supposed to be `list.append(string)`?

Comment: FYI: You should get out of the habit of using `for i in range(len(...))` Use `for item in ...` instead.

Comment: If you want to split a string with multiple delimiters, consider using `re.split()` instead of a loop like this.

Comment: And if you just want to search for a word in text, use a regexp: `fr"\b{item}\n"`

Comment: Protip: Don't use `list` as a variable name, because it shadows the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) type.

Comment: Why can't you replace that entire function with `return item in text`?

Comment: i can't just do that because it will return True also when 'item' is in another word. Fore example 'in' as item will return True also at: information, input ecc..

Comment: Why don't you just debug this in the debugger?  Surely you could make that effort.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that does work. It uses a regular expression to determine what the "words" are in the text, which in my opinion is the crux of the problem. It puts them all in a `set` and then uses that to determine if the `item` passed is a member of by using the `in` operator.

```
import re


WORD_PATTERN = re.compile("([\w][\w']*\w)")  # Regex to find words in a string.
                                             # see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12705513/355230

def search(text, item):
    words = {*WORD_PATTERN.findall(text)}  # Set for fast membership testing.
    return item in words


if __name__ == '__main__':

    s = "John's mom went there, but he wasn't there. So she said: 'Where are you?'"

    for word in ('mom', 'bug', 'so', 'So', "wasn't"):
        print(f'{word!r} in string s -> {search(s, word)}')
```

Printed output:

```
'mom' in string s -> True
'bug' in string s -> False
'so' in string s -> False
'So' in string s -> True
"wasn't" in string s -> True
```

As you can see the search are case-sensitive. Also note there are some subtleties with respect to the treatment of apostrophes — see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12705513/355230) where I got the regex from for details.