# Find if list contains something from string

Tags: python

I have a list that contains specific words - I want to find out if something from a string is found in the list.

Here's my code:

```
words = ["Lorem", "facilisis", "consectetur", "iaculis", "dolor"]

message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. " \
          "Aliquam aliquet facilisis orci, scelerisque iaculis odio dignissim nec. " \
          "Vestibulum luctus erat sit amet suscipit commodo"
BA = None
QA = None
EX = None

for i in message:
    if i == words:
        BA = i

print(f"Word found: {BA}")
```

**Output:** `Word found: None`

What's the mistake here?

Comment: `i` is a string, and `words` is a list. How then could "`i == words`" possibly be true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
words_found = [word for word in words if word in message]
```

Comment: Yeah, I definitely will. It takes 10 mins to do so though.

Comment: Code-only, introducing an advanced without explanation to a beginner. What makes the difference from a comment?

Comment: Where is the answer to the question "What's the mistake here?" ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Issues

Your for-loop iterates **over each character** in the `message`. So it has 176 iterations, each checking if **character is list** (! probably not what you want): `if i == words`

#### Solution

Other than [answered by Riccardo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71269127/5730279) with the elegant and concise but advanced construct of [*list-comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) you could also fix your loop:

(A) You can either just turn your search around `if word in message`.

(B) Alternatively first [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the `message` to chunks (words), e.g. by whitespace as delimiter. Then iterate over each of those chunks and test if in your list.

```
words = ["Lorem", "facilisis", "consectetur", "iaculis", "dolor"]

message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. " \
          "Aliquam aliquet facilisis orci, scelerisque iaculis odio dignissim nec. " \
          "Vestibulum luctus erat sit amet suscipit commodo"

# (A) in approach 
for w in words:
    if w in message:
        print(f"(A) Word found: {w}")

# (B) split approach 
for chunk in message.split():
    if chunk in words:
        print(f"(B) Word found: {chunk}")
```

Prints a different ordered but same set of 5 words for each approach:

```
(A) Word found: Lorem
(A) Word found: facilisis
(A) Word found: consectetur
(A) Word found: iaculis
(A) Word found: dolor
(B) Word found: Lorem
(B) Word found: dolor
(B) Word found: consectetur
(B) Word found: facilisis
(B) Word found: iaculis
```

Note: the default separator when invoking `str.split()` without arguments is a *whitespace* (space, tab, new-line, etc.).

#### Bonus: improved splitting

To not only split on a single *separator* character or default *whitespace* use the [`string` constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html?highlight=strings#string-constants) like:

- `string.whitespace`, or regex equivalent shorthand `\s`
- `string.punctuation`

in combination with [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) (split by regular-expression)
you can even improve your split and find words next to a line-break like `'Vestibulum'` or words next to a punctuation-mark like `['amet', 'elit', 'orci', 'nec']`:

```
message = "\tLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. " \
          "Aliquam aliquet facilisis orci, scelerisque iaculis odio dignissim nec.\n" \
          "Vestibulum luctus erat sit amet suscipit commodo"
words = ['amet', 'elit', 'orci', 'nec', 'Vestibulum']

import string
import re

sep_regex = '['+string.punctuation+'\s]'  # use \s instead string.whitespace
chunks = re.split(sep_regex, message)
found_words = [w for w in chunks if w in words]
print(found_words)
```

Prints:

```
['amet', 'elit', 'orci', 'nec', 'Vestibulum', 'amet']
```

Note: It contains `'amet'` twice because it was found twice. To get only the unique words found convert it to a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) using `set(found_words)`

See also:

- [Regex to split words in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705293/regex-to-split-words-in-python)
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/230126/string-operation-to-split-on-punctuation

Answer (score 0):

In your codes, `for i in message:` is going to traverse the characters not words. So minimum edit to achieve what you need should be:

```
for i in message.split(' '):
```

Comment: True, although that was already answered (duplicating/plagiarizing).

Comment: What happens with words at line-end or at punctuation marks when applying this space delimiter `' '` ?

Comment: Nothing happens. You can just test it by creating one string with spaces within and at the end, and use this function to see what happened.

Comment: Sure, that nothing happens? It does not find `world` (at punctuation-mark), nor `find` (at new-line) in `'Hello, world,\nfind my words!'`.